# What does x equivalent to 2 mod 15 mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, self-learning, congruences

I came across the following question:

Consider the following system of equivalences of integers.

$$ x \equiv 2 \bmod{15} $$

$$ x \equiv 4 \bmod{21} $$

The number of solutions in $x$, where $1\le x\le 315$, to the above system of equivalences is

(A) $0$
(B) $1$
(C) $2$
(D) $3$.

Can someone please explain to me what do $x \equiv 2 \bmod{15} $ and $ x \equiv 4 \bmod{21} $ mean?

I know that `mod` gives the remainder when the former number is divided by the latter like `15 mod 4 = 3`.

I need some help about how to solve this sum.

Comment: Computer scientists and programmers treat mod as a binary operation, taking in two inputs and producing one output. *Mathematicians* treat modulo as a family of *binary relations* between two numbers, one such relation for each possible modulus. The relation $a\equiv b$ mod $n$ means that $a$ and $b$ differ by a multiple of $n$, or in other words that the difference $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$, or equivalently that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder upon division by $n$.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you a nifty formula that will take you straight to the answer, but it doesn't sound like you are ready for that.  You need to build up some intuition with these sorts of questions...  so try this.

$x \equiv 2\mod15$ would be the same thing as $x = 15n + 2$ where $n$ is an integer.  And from the other equation $x = 21m+4$

Now, I leave it to you to do the tough part of finding a combination of $m$ and $n$ that solves both equations.

Comment: I noticed that $$ x \equiv 2 \bmod{15} $$
 implies x=17,32,47,62,77,92,107 and $$ x \equiv 4 \bmod{21} $$
 implies that x=25,46,67,88,109. So there are no values of x upto 105 (lcm of 15, 21). Hence there r no such values and the answer is (A). I checked upto the LCM because i intuitively felt that the cycle would start repeating itself there onwards. Am i correct on this?

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv2\pmod{15}$ means that $15$ divides $x-2$
$x\equiv4\pmod{21}$ means that $21$ divides $x-4$

The equations
$$
\begin{align}
x&\equiv2\pmod{15}&\implies &&x&\equiv2\pmod{3}\\
x&\equiv4\pmod{21}&\implies &&x&\equiv1\pmod{3}\\
\end{align}
$$
are inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think OP is familiar with the "divides" symbol, perhaps you should add that.

Answer (score 0):

$$a \equiv b \pmod m \iff m\mid b-a \iff \exists k\ \text{ s.t. }\ mk = b-a$$

The relevant lemma here states: A solution exists iff $2\equiv 4 \pmod{\gcd(15,21)} \iff 2\equiv 4 \pmod 3$.  Using the above definition, is this true?